# How to refresh shape data file in spotfire

Tags: geospatial, data-analysis, shapefile, spotfire, qgis

I am a beginner in working with geospatial data. What I have done so far:

1. I created a map chart visualization in spotfire.
2. I created a shape file using QGIS.
3. I added the shapefile in the spotfire using Add Data Table -> File
4. I added a feature layer into map chart and used/applied the shapefile data.

So far so good.

But now I guess the shape file is static data?

How can I refresh the shape file so that it reflects the changes in the underlying base database? BTW the base or master data is in Oracle.

Versions:

- OS - Windows 8.1
- QGIS - 3.0.1
- Spotfire - 7.11.0

This is the first time I am using either spotfire and qgis.